# What system do you use to name your logos?

Tags: logo, asset-management

I'm in a corporate marketing department that has LOADS of logos for our main brand and all of our sub brands, departments, divisions, etc. The logos are typically the family name and the sub division under it (SMITH Brokerage, SMITH Administrative Services, SMITH Benefits... The name has been changed to protect the innocent). They can be either horizontal or vertical.

Now, I'm not here to argue that there are too many logos or brands (dozens)... There are, but this is what I have to work with.

The main logo is composed of 3 PMS colors, there is a 4 Color version, 1 PMS 343 version, 1 PMS 124 version, a black version, a KO version, etc. All developed for a variety of mediums, different color backgrounds, promotional items, etc. All of the sub brands follow the same pattern and primary elements.

So, how to organize them? How to name them? Do you have a cool way of naming your logos so that they are easy to find and use? Would you mind sharing? What I am trying to clean up is 30+ years of organic growth and tons of logos. It's a mess!!

Thanks!
-M

Comment: Binary: 01110011011011010110100101110100011010000010000000110001.pdf

Comment: Is 01110011011011010110100101110100011010000010000000110001.pdf descriptive enough though? I think, 010110010110111101110101010100100110010101100001011011000110110001111001010101110110010101101110011101000101010001101000011100100110111101110101011001110110100001010100011010000110010101000101011001100110011001101111011100100111010001001111011001100101010001110010011000010110111001110011011011000110000101110100011010010110111001100111010101000110100001101001011100110100001001100001011000110110101101010100011011110100010101101110011001110110110001101001011100110110100000111111.pdf, is better.

Answer (score 5):

We usually name our logos by the following scheme:

```
Logo_[BRAND]_[DEPARTMENT]_[SLOGAN]_[COLORS]_[PROFILE].ext
```

e.g.

- Logo_Acme-Inc_Finance_with-Slogan-2014_BLACK_RGB.ai
- Logo_Acme-Inc_Finance_with-Slogan-2014_BLACK_PANTONE.ai
- Logo_Acme-Inc_Sales_no-Slogan_FULL-COLOR_CMYK.ai
- Logo_Acme-Inc_Sales_no-Slogan_FULL-COLOR_RGB.ai

…and so on. This works for us and our clients. You'll find all the Logos in one place and also know what you'll get before opening a file.